# Create a text file table with java with padding

Tags: java, arrays, text-files, padding

Since my last text and question was very vague here is my source as of now and a clearer question. It is all about the padding now.

Here is my code up to now:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class makeTable {


static ArrayList<String> val1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("field1", "field1val2", "field1val3"));
static ArrayList<String> val2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("field2", "field2val2", "field2val3"));
static int col1=15;
static int col2=15;

public static void main(String arg[]) {

BufferedWriter writeTable = null;
try {
    writeTable = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:/testtable.txt"));

    //Anfang erste Zeile
    writeTable.write("+ ");
    for (int i = 0; i < col1; i++){
        writeTable.write("-");   
    }
    writeTable.write(" + ");
    for (int i = 0; i < col2; i++){
        writeTable.write("-");   
    }
    writeTable.write(" +");
    writeTable.newLine();
    //Ende erste Zeile

    for (int i = 0; i < val1.size(); i++){
        writeTable.write("| " + val1.get(i) + "   "+ " + " +"   "+ val2.get(i) +  "   "+ " |");
        writeTable.newLine();

        writeTable.write("+ ");
        for (int j = 0; j < col1; j++){
            writeTable.write("-");   
        }
        writeTable.write(" + ");
        for (int m = 0; m < col2; m++){
            writeTable.write("-");   
        }
        writeTable.write(" +");
        writeTable.newLine(); 

    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println(e);
} finally {
    if (writeTable != null) {
        try {
            writeTable.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
}
}
```

Now I need to add a padding so that the result looks like :

```
+ -------------- + -------------- +
|     field1     |     filed2     |
+ -------------- + -------------- + 
|   field1val2   |   field2val2   | 
+ -------------- + -------------- +
```

and so on. It need to be centered. I can only think of adding something like val1.get(i).length() /2 and that is the amount of " " to add.... but how can I do that?

I cannot use other libraries (3rd party ones).

Comment: What is your problem exactly? How to write to a file? Or how to get that pattern?

Comment: primarily how to get the pattern of the table with the values.

Comment: This little library may be helpful: https://github.com/assylias/Java-Text-Table-Formatter

Comment: @Marged assylias wrote that comment before I specified that point of not being able to use other libraries, that's why I added the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code below change `append` with `StringBuilder` with `BufferedWriter`.

```
public void appendCentered(StringBuilder sb, String s, int width) {
    if (s.length() > width) {
        s = s.substring(0, width);
    }
    int spaces = width - s.length();
    int before = spaces / 2;
    int after = spaces - before; // Could be 1 more than 'before'.
    appendSpaces(sb, before);
    sb.append(s);
    appendSpaces(sb, after);
}

public void appendSpaces(StringBuilder sb, int width) {
    while (width-- > 0) {
        sb.append(' ');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are the results of your program after I centered the text.

```
+ -------------- + -------------- +
|     field1     +     field2     |
+ -------------- + -------------- +
|   field1val2   +   field2val2   |
+ -------------- + -------------- +
|   field1val3   +   field2val3   |
+ -------------- + -------------- +
```

Here are the changes I made.

1. The biggest thing that I did was break your monolithic code into methods.  By writing small methods, you can break your larger task into smaller tasks.  The smaller tasks are easier to code.
2. A class name starts with a capital letter.  I renamed makeTable to MakeTable.
3. I changed your code to use the List interface, rather than the ArrayList class.  By using the interface, it makes it easier in the future to change the type of List.  I can use a LinkedList by changing 2 lines of your code.
4. The main method now just creates the output.  I couldn't write directly to the C drive on my Windows 8.1 laptop.  I had to create the file in the same directory as the code.
5. The writeDashedLine method writes a dashed line.  I use the code in 2 places, but by putting the code into a method, I only had to write the code once.
6. The writeDashes method writes the dashes part of a dashed line.  Again, I use the code in 2 places, but by putting the code into a method, I only had to write the code once.
7. The writeValueLine method writes the values on a line.  I use the code in one place, but to be consistent with the writeDashedLine method, I wrote a method for the code.
8. The rest of the methods are what I wrote to center text.  First, I found the longest value in the 2 lists of values.  Next, I added the 4 characters of padding.  Next, I centered the text by adding padding to the front and the back of the String.

Study these methods so you can do this type of task in the future.

Here's the formatted code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MakeTable {

    static List<String> val1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("field1",
            "field1val2", "field1val3"));
    static List<String> val2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("field2",
            "field2val2", "field2val3"));

    static int length = getLongestValue(val1, val2) + 4;

    public static void main(String arg[]) {

        BufferedWriter writeTable = null;
        try {
            writeTable = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("testtable.txt"));

            writeDashedLine(writeTable);
            writeTable.newLine();
            // Ende erste Zeile

            for (int i = 0; i < val1.size(); i++) {
                writeValueLine(writeTable, val1.get(i), val2.get(i));
                writeTable.newLine();

                writeDashedLine(writeTable);
                writeTable.newLine();

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        } finally {
            if (writeTable != null) {
                try {
                    writeTable.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void writeDashedLine(BufferedWriter writeTable)
            throws IOException {
        // Anfang erste Zeile
        writeTable.write("+ ");
        writeDashes(writeTable);
        writeTable.write(" + ");
        writeDashes(writeTable);
        writeTable.write(" +");
    }

    public static void writeDashes(BufferedWriter writeTable)
            throws IOException {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            writeTable.write("-");
        }
    }

    public static void writeValueLine(BufferedWriter writeTable, String value1,
            String value2) throws IOException {
        writeTable.write("| " + centerText(value1, length) + " + "
                + centerText(value2, length) + " |");
    }

    public static String centerText(String text, int length) {
        int textLength = text.length();
        if (textLength > length) {
            return text.substring(0, length);
        } else if (textLength == length) {
            return text;
        } else {
            int diff1 = (length - textLength) / 2;
            int diff2 = length - textLength - diff1;
            return getPadding(' ', diff1) + text + getPadding(' ', diff2);
        }
    }

    public static String getPadding(char pad, int length) {
        String padding = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            padding += pad;
        }

        return padding;
    }

    public static int getLongestValue(List<String> val1, List<String> val2) {
        int length = 0;

        for (String s : val1) {
            length = Math.max(length, s.length());
        }

        for (String s : val2) {
            length = Math.max(length, s.length());
        }

        return length;
    }
}
```